Why is the Dirac point of the pristine monolayer Graphene above the Fermi level in the calculation with Quantum Espresso?
I am running a test calculation for the band structure of the pristine monolayer graphene with $4\times4\times1$ supercell through Quantum Espresso (QE).
This is my input file.
&CONTROL
   title = 'SLG_441',
   calculation = 'scf',
   restart_mode = 'from_scratch',
   pseudo_dir = './'
/
&SYSTEM
   ibrav = 0,
   nat = 32,
   ntyp = 1,
   ecutwfc = 50,
   ecutrho = 200,
   nbnd = 156,
   occupations = 'smearing',
   degauss = 1d-9,
   smearing = 'gaussian'
/
&ELECTRONS
   electron_maxstep = 100,
   conv_thr = 1.0d-9,
   mixing_mode = 'plain',
   mixing_beta = 0.8d0,
   diagonalization = 'david'
/
&IONS
    ion_positions = 'from_input'
/
&CELL
    cell_dynamics = 'none'
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
   C  12.0 C.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
CELL_PARAMETERS (angstrom)
   9.8400000000      0.0000000000      0.0000000000
  -4.9200000000      8.5216901054      0.0000000000
   0.0000000000      0.0000000000     23.4000000000
ATOMIC_POSITIONS (angstrom)
C   0.0000000000      0.0000000000     11.7000000000
C   1.2300000367      0.7101408633     11.7000000000
C  -1.2300000000      2.1304225263     11.7000000000
C   0.0000000367      2.8405633896     11.7000000000
C  -2.4600000000      4.2608450527     11.7000000000
C  -1.2299999633      4.9709859160     11.7000000000
C  -3.6900000000      6.3912675790     11.7000000000
C  -2.4599999633      7.1014084423     11.7000000000
C   2.4600000000      0.0000000000     11.7000000000
C   3.6900000367      0.7101408633     11.7000000000
C   1.2300000000      2.1304225263     11.7000000000
C   2.4600000367      2.8405633896     11.7000000000
C   0.0000000000      4.2608450527     11.7000000000
C   1.2300000367      4.9709859160     11.7000000000
C  -1.2300000000      6.3912675790     11.7000000000
C   0.0000000367      7.1014084423     11.7000000000
C   4.9200000000      0.0000000000     11.7000000000
C   6.1500000367      0.7101408633     11.7000000000
C   3.6900000000      2.1304225263     11.7000000000
C   4.9200000367      2.8405633896     11.7000000000
C   2.4600000000      4.2608450527     11.7000000000
C   3.6900000367      4.9709859160     11.7000000000
C   1.2300000000      6.3912675790     11.7000000000
C   2.4600000367      7.1014084423     11.7000000000
C   7.3800000000      0.0000000000     11.7000000000
C   8.6100000367      0.7101408633     11.7000000000
C   6.1500000000      2.1304225263     11.7000000000
C   7.3800000367      2.8405633896     11.7000000000
C   4.9200000000      4.2608450527     11.7000000000
C   6.1500000367      4.9709859160     11.7000000000
C   3.6900000000      6.3912675790     11.7000000000
C   4.9200000367      7.1014084423     11.7000000000
K_POINTS automatic
11 11 1 1 1 1

I am using C.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF pseudopotential with the details below.
Origin: PS Library
Author: ADC 
Generated using "atomic" code by A. Dal Corso  v.6.3
Pseudopotential type: PAW 
Functional type: PBE
Non Linear Core Correction
Scalar relativistic

I found that the Dirac point is located 0.027 eV above the Fermi energy level, shown in the figure blow. Obviously, it is not correct.

Would anyone please give me some suggestions on my input file?
Thank you in advance.

It is likely your k-point sampling, try 12 k-points! Better yet, converge the number of k-points as one should always do!

@nickpapior Thank you for the reply. I re-ran the test calculation with $21\times21\times1$ k point sampling again but the Dirac point is still 0.027 eV above the Fermi energy level. I suspect that the proble is from the pseudopotential but I do not have proper one. Would you please recommend an accurate pseudopotential for the C element to me? Thank you again.

Why don't you ask for an accurate pseudopotential for C, in a separate post?

@Nike Dattani Thank you for your suggestions. Do I need to close this post before I ask for an accurate pseudopotential for carbon element in another new post?

@Kieran you do not need to close this post. It is perfectly okay to have several posts open at the same time, but it is requested that each new question comes in a new post.
